# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: set_session cannot be used inside a transaction

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save objects in DB [obj.save()] with the help of ORMs. But it throws the following error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: set_session cannot be used inside a transaction

Does any ideas about this error?

I am using Django & PostgresDB

Comment: Show us the full error and traceback, and the code that results in this.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug of psysopg2 for that you can install older version of psysopg2 for now i was having same issue so I installed older and balanced version of psysopg2. so this one you can try this command to install

`pip install psycopg2==2.6.2`

may be this will work

Comment: psycopg2 2.9.1 works absolutely fine for me, so I'm not sure downgrading it is a proper fix.

Comment: So I will check about this if I found another solution I will edit answer

Comment: can you just try commenting this line in setings.py ```DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django_postgrespool'```